# OCaml: Issues linking C and OCaml

Tags: c, ocaml, linker-errors

I am able to wrap C code and access it from the OCaml interpreter, but cannot build a binary! I'm 98% sure it is some linking problem, but can't find the tools to explore the linkage.

Getting even to this point was a chore, (endless quantities of `Error: The external function is not available` messages) so I'll document everything I did.

A 'system' file `stuff.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun(int z)  // Emulate a "real" subroutine
{
        printf("duuude whoa z=%d\n", z);
        return 42;
}
```

Compile above as

```
cc -fPIC -c stuff.c
ld -shared -o libstuff.so stuff.o
```

An OCaml wrapper around above, in `ocmstuff.c`:

```
#include <caml/mlvalues.h>
CAMLprim value yofun(value z) {
    return Val_long(fun(Long_val(z)));
}
```

Build above as

```
cc -fPIC -c ocmstuff.c
ld -shared -o dllostuff.so ocmstuff.o -L . -lstuff -lc -rpath .
```

Yes, the rpath really is needed, else the next steps suffer. (*Edit:* If you don't use rpath, you'll need to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` instead. For the final 'production' version, you'd change the rpath to the actual library path, or do `ld.so.conf` trickery or install into 'standard' locations, or tell your users about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This is just like what you'd do for any other system. The rpath solution seems to be the most stable and reliable solution.)

Next, a module declaration, stored in `fapi.mli`

```
module Fapi : sig
        external ofun : int -> int = "yofun" ;;
end
```

Build above as:

```
ocamlc -a -o fapi.cma -intf fapi.mli -dllib -lostuff
```

Does it work? Yes it does:

```
$ rlwrap ocaml fapi.cma
        OCaml version 4.11.1
open Fapi ;;
Fapi.ofun 33 ;;
duuude whoa z=33
- : int = 42
#
```

So the wrapper works fine.  Now lets compile with it.  Here's `myprog.ml`:

```
open Fapi ;;
Fapi.ofun 33 ;;
```

Compile it:

```
ocamlc -c myprog.ml
ocamlc -o myprog myprog.cmo fapi.cma
```

The very last command spews:

```
File "_none_", line 1:
Error: Required module `Fapi' is unavailable
```

I am 98% sure the above error is due to some silly linking error, but I cannot track it down. Why do I think this? Well, here's a related problem that provides a hint.

```
$ rlwrap ocaml
open Fapi ;;
# Fapi.ofun 33 ;;
Error: The external function `yofun' is not available
#
```

Well, that's odd. It clearly must have found `fapi.cma` because that is the only way it can know about `yofun`. But somehow, it doesn't know it needs to dig into `dllostuff.so` for that.  Or possibly `dllostuff.so` is failing to correctly link/load `libstuff.so` ? Or maybe `libc.so` to get `printf` ? I'm pretty sure its one of these last few, but I just can't get it to work, and don't have the tools to debug it. (`nm` and `ldd -r` look healthy. Are there some similar tools for the assorted cma,cmo,cmi,cmx files?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfacing with C is much easier if you use [dune](https://jbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html#defining-a-library-with-c-stubs). You don't need to know the low-level details it is all handled for you.

Now, back to your example. This is definitely not how OCaml users are interfacing with C, but if you really want to learn about it here are a few notes.

The reason why you have the error is that:

1. you specified modules in an incorrect order, it should be topological, not reverse topological order, i.e., the dependency comes before dependent
2. you do not have the `.ml` file (the `-intf` option means very different)

The reason why the last snippet doesn't work is because you're not loading the library. The `ocaml` binary obviously doesn't have any `fapi` units linked into it, so you have to explicitly load it using either `#load` directive or by passing it in the command line.

Also the following line is not necessary,

```
ld -shared -o dllostuff.so ocstuff.o -L . -lstuff -lc -rpath .
```

First of all, there is no need to link a stub file into a shared library. It is counterproductive and doesn't really bring you anything. Second, passing `-rpath .` will render the end executable unusable, unless the shared objects are stored in the same folder as the executable. Just remove this.

Just to complete your exercise, here is how it could be built and run. First, let's fix the stub file. We need the `ml` file and we also need to remove an extra module definition,

```
$ cat fapi.{ml,mli}
external ofun : int -> int = "yofun" ;;
external ofun : int -> int = "yofun" ;;
```

Yes, they are the same. The `mli` file is not really needed here, but let's keep it for the sake of completeness.

The way how you build the pure C part is fine, as long as you get a relocatable .so file it works.

Now to build the `ocstuff.c` (which we conventionally call stubs) you just need to do,

```
ocamlc -c ocstuff.c
```

Don't turn it into a shared library, don't do anything else with it. Now let's build the `fapi` library,

```
ocamlc -c fapi.mli
ocamlc -c fapi.ml
```

Now let's build the library that contains both OCaml and C code,

```
ocamlmklib -o fapi fapi.cmo ocstuff.o -lstuff -L.
```

Now we can finally build the executable,

```
ocamlc -c myprog.ml 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ocamlc -o myprog fapi.cma myprog.cmo
```

and run it,

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./myprog 
duuude whoa z=33
```

Notice that we have to use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to tell the *system* dynamic loader where to look for the external dependency `libstuff.so`. You can, of course, use `rpath` to specify its location (pass it to `ocamlmklib` via `-ccopt`) but in general it is assumed that the external library is installed at some location that the system loader knows.

Again, unless you're developing your own build system, please use dune or oasis for building OCaml programs. These systems will handle all low-level details in the best possible way.

P.S. It is also worth mentioning that you're not building a binary, but a bytecode executable. For binaries, you will have to use the `ocamlopt` compiler. And this would be a completely different story. Again, dune is the solution.

Comment: I will try this now. Be aware this is a demo: the project is built with CMake, and has evaluators for python, haskell, scheme and has c++ bindings. I'm trying to add an OCaml evaluator, inter-operable with the others. Switching to dune from CMake would be massive undertaking.

Comment: yep, I got it that is a demo, so yes in this case you will have to learn all the low-level details. Don't worry OCaml is very easy interfacable with any build system (I used it with cmake and even bjam), but there are few things to learn and some conventions to discover. I would suggest looking at other projects that provide OCaml  bindings, e.g., z3 would be an example, https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/scripts/mk_util.py

Comment: FYI, Based on your post, I was able to reconstruct what I did wrong. Basically, two issues: the name `dllostuff.so` was wrong, it really needed to be `dllfapi.so` to be consistent. That, and the need for both the `mli` and `ml` files describing the externals. With these two fixes, my original recipe works.

Comment: I would still suggest you use `ocamlmklib` as it will make your build setup more portable across different operating systems, e.g., windows and macOS have different conventions in the library names.

Comment: I now have the issue that I need to install both the `cma` and also the `cmi` file in order for `open` to work. That's a surprise, but `ocamlobjinfo` shows the `Unit name:` also appearing under `Interface imported:`. (Earlier experiments done in the test dir, without installing.)

Comment: Sigh. Also saying `#load /some/path/to/thing.cma" ;;` is not enough to get `open Thing ;;` to work. Instead, I have to start `ocaml` with `$ ocaml -I /some/path/to` for the `open` to work. This is quite the struggle.

Comment: Use the `#directory` directive or build a custom toplevel. Also think about proper building a package, with a META file, so that you can load it with the `#require` directive from ocamlfind and do not bother about the locations.

Comment: And yes, cmx, cmi, cmo, cma, cmxs, all these files have to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to take in here, but these lines are suspicious:

```
ocamlc -c myprog.ml
ocamlc -o myprog myprog.cmo fapi.cma
```

OCaml expects modules in topologically sorted order, with a module appearing on the command line before the modules that refer to it.

So it would seem the last line should be this:

```
ocamlc -o myprog fapi.cma myprog.cmo
```

I hope this helps, it's just a quick response.

Comment: Just tried it, makes no difference. Of course, "Topological order" is what everyone uses, but the standard convention is opposite of what you've stated. For example, in C, you say `libc.so` last, not first. The idea is to resolve more and more symbols as one moves from left to right.

Comment: The definition of topological ordering is exactly that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting
In C, mostly due to historical reasons, they use *reverse* topological ordering. Which is a common source of problems.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by ivg works. It also provides enough hints to retrofit the original question to get the correct behavior. The changes to the original recipe are:

- Create `fapi.mli` and `fapi.ml` which both have the same content: `external ofun : int -> int = "yofun" ;;`
- Compile both the above with `ocaml -c`. The `mli` must be compiled first: it yields an interface file  `cmi` which is needed before the `ml` file can be compiled into it's object file `cmo`.
- The name `dllostuff.so` was wrong: it must be `dllfapi.so` to maintain naming consistency.
- Build the `cma` archive/library as `ocamlc -a -o fapi.cma fapi.cmo -dllib -lfapi`

That's it! Other than these, the original instructions work.  The answer from ivg suggests using

```
ocamlmklib -o fapi fapi.cmo ostuff.o -L. -lstuff
```

instead of

```
ld -shared -o dllfapi.so ostuff.o -L. -lstuff
```

Either of these work. The primary difference is that `ocamlmklib` also creates a static-linked library `libfapi.a`. Other than that, it creates the `dllfapi.so` as before. (That version also contains a motley assortment of typical gcc symbols, for handling exceptions, library ctors, *etc.* It's not clear why these are needed here, since they'll show up sooner or later anyway.)